# Exporting Google Calendar to goggle sheet - issues with sorting from newest to oldest

Tags: sorting, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

How do I get this script to re-order so that when it exports the data the most recent entries are at the top? At the moment it puts the oldest data a the top.

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet() {
    var mycal = "Email";
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
    var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("July 01, 2022 00:00:00 UTC"), new Date ("September 12, 2022 23:59:59 UTC"));
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clearContents();  
    var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event"]]
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 14);
    range.setValues(header);
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var row=i+2;
        var myformula_placeholder = '';
        var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
        var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,14);
        range.setValues(details);
        var cell=sheet.getRange(row,7);
        cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
        cell.setNumberFormat('.00');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. About `Hi Tanaike - I can't get it to work for some reason, the target sheet just comes up blank. I'm still testing it thought. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong. YOur code is much simpler.`, I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. I could understood that my answer for reducing the process cost was not useful for your situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I have to study more.

Comment: @Tanaike no mate you did a good job, I'm actually sure it works, I'm just a beginner so there is so much that I'm sure that I missed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `no mate you did a good job, I'm actually sure it works, I'm just a beginner so there is so much that I'm sure that I missed.`, I think that your skill has no problem. I think that the reason, that the script doesn't show your expected result, is due to just my poor skill. I would like to study more and would like to propose 
 a useful proposal. In the current stage, I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modify the Formula in your For Loop

In your for loop, modify the formula for your row from:

`var row=i+2;`

to:

`var row = events.length + 1 - i;`

This will display the most recent entry the top of the row.